# Angular 4, socket IO connection with spring Websocket

Tags: angular, spring-websocket, socket.io-1.0

I have been trying to connect Angular 4 to Spring Websockets. The backend code works fine but I had hard time from client connections. I have used socket.io-client from npm but have received some error while connection. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

**1. Socket.io-Client**
This is my app.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
//import { Control }           from '@angular/common';
import { WebsocketService }       from './websocket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
                     {{message.text}}
                   </div>
                   <input [(ngModel)]="message"  /><button (click)="sendMessage()">Send</button>`,
  providers:[WebsocketService],
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

  messages = [];
  connection;
  message;

  constructor(private chatService:WebsocketService) {}

  sendMessage(){
    this.chatService.sendMessage(this.message);
    this.message = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.connection = this.chatService.getMessages().subscribe(message => {
      this.messages.push(message);
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.connection.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

The corresponding service file being used to call is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
//import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {
  private url = 'ws://localhost:8080/socket';
  private socket;
  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(this.url);
  }



  sendMessage(message){
    this.socket.emit('add-message', message);
  }

  getMessages() {
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {

      this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };
    })
    return observable;
  }
}
```

Everytime I compile and run the code, I see polling error in the network tab of my browser.

[image: Error in browser]

The backend code goes like this in spring boot

The WebBrokerConfig file is

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketBrokerConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry){
        System.out.println("Received message for the Broker");
        registry
                .enableSimpleBroker("/chat");
    }
}
```

the controller is

```
Controller

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class QuestionController {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    QuestionController(SimpMessagingTemplate template){
        this.template = template;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/send/message")
    public void onReceivedMessage(String message){
        System.out.println("received message for question mapping for the controller");
        this.template.convertAndSend( "/chat", new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())+ message);

    }
```

Comment: is there any error in the console? both browser and server

Comment: There is no error at the server side. The console says the resource returned 404 status and the CORS error which I have handled at the controller of spring code. but when I see network tab, all the websocket and info connections are successful

Comment: Did you manage to fix it finally?

Comment: I have run into the same problem, did you find a solution ? 
I guess either a) front: socket.io keep as it is,spring: implement the netty solution (socket.io for java) b) front: implement with sockjs and stomp messages , spring: keep as it is

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can this way. You are mixing two different libraries.

I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73972403/spring-boot-angular-websocket-libraries-choice-and-communication)

I think the final choice would be between the two below. StompJS on both , or Socket.io on both

1. Spring: regular spring-websocket broker, with Stomp. Angular StompJS
   and SockJS
2. Spring: [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) which is a port of socketIO.
   Angular Socket.IO

Please correct me if I am wrong